# How to copy ssl certificate from centOS 7 to windows?

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I have copied ssl certificate from te ELK server, set up on cent OS 7, with this command

```
scp /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt user@client_server_private_address:/tmp
```

but then how should I place it into the Windows 2012 r2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly copy the .crt file with ***sudo vi*** from the centOS to your windows destination folder, i.e. inside beats file